# Ask about right-angle

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

What do you mean when you say "An apartment doesn't have a single right angle"? Does it just mean this apartment doesn't have any 90-degree angle? Or it has another meaning? If this is the former, then what kind of apartment doesn't have a right angle?

Comment: I would understand it as referring to the floor plan of the apartment; that the walls were connected at other angles than right angles. Apartments designed that way are not very common, but it happens in other types of buildings a lot.

Comment: It could mean anything, without context there's no saying. Please take the tour: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour and read about what we expect you to do in asking questions: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that it "doesn't have a single right-angle" is a general comment about workmanship rather than design. It suggests that the quality of workmanship is poor in an apartment where the walls are expected to be (but are not) at right-angles to the floor, or where the the ceiling is expected to be (but is not) the same height off the ground at all points, or the room corners are expected to be right-angles (but are not), or, finally, where the floor is expected to be level (but is not).

Comment: Or it could be in a crescent (a block of houses with a curved façade, so the back walls are longer than the front ones, or occasionally vice-versa).